# Why are functions like "Point" / "Rect" / "Bounds" (etc) declared both in Classes and in Types unit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have noticed that in Delphi 7 functions like `Point` / `Rect` / `Bounds` (etc) are declared and implemented both in `Classes` and in system `Types` unit.

Is there a reason for that? is it also true for newer Delphi versions?

(My guess is that one could use `Types` unit to avoid the `Classes` overhead when needed)

Comment: Module `Classes` includes `Types`, so the reason will be something else than you guess. And it's the same in Tokyo (probably for backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In older versions these types and functions were declared in `Classes`. As the RTL was developed, especially to support cross-platform, it became desirable for the these types to be available to units that did not include `Classes`.

The `Types` unit was introduced to enable that. The `Types` unit has no `uses` dependencies so can safely be used by any other unit, no matter how low level.

The master declarations were moved to `Types`, and `Classes` re-exports these types and functions for the benefit of existing code that imports from `Classes`. So for instance, `SysUtils` uses `Types`, but is not permitted to use `Classes`. Moving these types and functions to a dependency free unit like `Types` enables that.

This change was made between Delphi 5 and Delphi 6, which was the start of the Delphi cross-platform developments. In that instance it was Kylix, but the restructuring of the RTL benefited the future cross-platform developments, even though Kylix was abandoned.